# Can one alter a PostgresSql table to have an autogenerated keys after the table has values?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-design, auto-increment, alter

Is it possible to only alter a table to make an existing column a serial auto generated key, without adding a new column? Sorry if this question is a bit newbie-ish for PostgreSQL, I'm more a SQL Server person but moving to PostgreSQL..

In a nut shell the program will copying an existing SQL Server database into PostgreSQL. With the desire to have a mirrored DB in PostgreSQL as the source from SQL Server with the only caveat one may selectively include/exclude any table or column as desired, or do everything...

Given the process copies all values, thought one should be able create the keys after the copy has finished just as one may do in SQL Server. Thought PostgreSQL would have a comparable methods as SQL Server's `SET INSERT_IDENTITY [ON|OFF]` so one may override the auto generated key with a desired value. Not seeing an equivalent in PostgreSQL. So my fallback is to create the mirrored records in Postgres without keys any keys and then alter the tables. But it seems to fix up the table as desired one has create a new column, but doing this break or cause a headache fixing up the RI for PK/FK relationships.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, the auto-generated key is *always* overridden if you insert an explicit value for it. If you don't specify a value (omit the column), or specify the keyword `DEFAULT`, a generated key is used.

Given table

```
 CREATE TABLE t1 (id serial primary key, dat text);
```

then both these will get a generated key from sequence `t1_id_seq`:

```
 INSERT INTO t1 (dat) VALUES ('fred');
 INSERT INTO t1 (id, dat) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'bob');
```

This will instead provide its own value:

```
 INSERT INTO t1 (id, dat) VALUES (42, 'joe');
```

You are responsible for ensuring that the provided value doesn't conflict with existing data, or with future values the identity sequence will generate. PostgreSQL will *not* notice that you manually inserted a row with id `42` and skip when its own sequence counter gets to that point.

Usually what you do is load with provided values, then reset the sequence to the max of all keys already in the table, so it keeps counting from there for new local inserts.